# Show batch of notifications once in an hour

Tags: macos, notifications, do-not-disturb

Lots of notifications distract from work but ignoring them is bad. Is there any possibility to receive all notifications like on every 0 minute of an hour.

Something like:

```
6:30 - New calendar notification [not shown, scheduled]  
6:31 - New skype notification [not shown, scheduled]  
6:45 - New slack notification [not shown, scheduled]  
7:00 - Show all notifications [calendar, skype, slack]
```

I tried to google how to do that, but I didn't find.

Comment: Is this for iOS or macOS or both?  Please add the relevant tags to your question.

Comment: @fsb done :) It's for macos

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think this is possible with native macOS (maybe others here  will know more about that) so are you open to using a 3rd-party application?

Comment: Just use do not disturb and check your notifications every so often. That way you can check in between tasks instead of being interrupted by 10 notifications while you're in the zone.

Comment: @fsb sure, I'm open :) If I knew macos development, I'd like to find something like interceptor for notifications

Comment: @JBallin that's the manual way to do that, I'd prefer more automatic

Comment: Awesome idea. I would pay for this app.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it! I created a focus profile that is scheduled to come on in 50-minute increments. That way, each hour the notifications will come up which were silenced during that 50-minute session. (see photo)[image]

Comment: Wow, a hack but sounds very nice! Thanks :)

Comment: That was precisely the idea that struck me.. when you exit focus state, your notifications which were held are all released. Great work illustrating the time based  workflow. I would probably use my watch to set a timer and then manually release the focus since sometimes I don’t want to surface for two intervals…

Comment: Is there a way to paste the image inline?